# Angular2 lazy loading module error 'cannot find module'

Tags: angular, module, lazy-loading

I was trying to find any solution for this error but nothing works for me. I have simple Angular2 App created with Angular-CLI. When I serve this app in browser I'm getting this error: `EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module '/app/test.module'.`  I was trying using different path in loadChildren:

```
'/app/test.module'
'./app/test.module'
'./test.module'
'/src/app/test.module'
```

**Folders**

```
src/
  app/
    app-routing.module.ts
    app.component.ts
    app.module.ts
    test.component.ts
    test.module.ts
```

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { RoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: '/app/test.module' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
})
export class RoutingModule { }
```

**test.module.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { TestComponent } from './test.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: TestComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [TestComponent],
  declarations: [TestComponent]
})
export default class TestModule { }
```

**stack trace**

```js
        error_handler.js:45EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module '/app/test.module'.ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:45next @ application_ref.js:273schedulerFn @ async.js:82SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89Subject.next @ Subject.js:55EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:74onError @ ng_zone.js:120onHandleError @ ng_zone_impl.js:64ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:207Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:113_loop_1 @ zone.js:379drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:386
    2016-10-08 14:22:50.612 error_handler.js:50ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:50next @ application_ref.js:273schedulerFn @ async.js:82SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89Subject.next @ Subject.js:55EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:74onError @ ng_zone.js:120onHandleError @ ng_zone_impl.js:64ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:207Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:113_loop_1 @ zone.js:379drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:386
    2016-10-08 14:22:50.613 error_handler.js:51Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module '/app/test.module'.
        at resolvePromise (zone.js:429)
        at zone.js:406
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:203)
        at Object.onInvoke (ng_zone_impl.js:43)
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:202)
        at Zone.run (zone.js:96)
        at zone.js:462
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:236)
        at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone_impl.js:34)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:235)ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:51next @ application_ref.js:273schedulerFn @ async.js:82SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89Subject.next @ Subject.js:55EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:74onError @ ng_zone.js:120onHandleError @ ng_zone_impl.js:64ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:207Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:113_loop_1 @ zone.js:379drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:386
    2016-10-08 14:22:50.614 zone.js:355Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot find module '/app/test.module'. ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Cannot find module '/app/test.module'.(…) Error: Cannot find module '/app/test.module'.
        at webpackEmptyContext (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:49550:8)
        at SystemJsNgModuleLoader.loadAndCompile (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:57952:40)
        at SystemJsNgModuleLoader.load (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:57945:60)
        at RouterConfigLoader.loadModuleFactory (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:22354:128)
        at RouterConfigLoader.load (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:22346:81)
        at MergeMapSubscriber.project (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:61105:111)
        at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:32515:27)
        at MergeMapSubscriber._next (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:32505:18)
        at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:7085:18)
        at ScalarObservable._subscribe (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:48555:24)consoleError @ zone.js:355_loop_1 @ zone.js:382drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:386
    2016-10-08 14:22:50.620 zone.js:357Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module '/app/test.module'.(…)consoleError @ zone.js:357_loop_1 @ zone.js:382drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:386
```

Comment: try `loadChildren: '/app/test.module'` to change to `loadChildren: 'app/test.module'` This will work I guess.

Comment: I tried this before but had the same error

Comment: I was troubled by this error all night. At last, I found I just need to stop the `ng serve` command, and restart. Then the error gone. Because the module will be lazy loaded, maybe there is some work will be done during starting test server.

Comment: @Mavlarn restart ng serve work for me as well, thanks !

Comment: @arthurr  did you use  `ng build --aot ` for compilation? cause I get this error only while doing --aot, otherwise it works fine

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya yes, I'm using -aot and I don't have this error any more. For me solution was to restart `ng serve` after adding new module to routes.

Comment: @arthurr I also got it work, for me the problem was `ngBusy` that dep. don't support `--aot` with lazy-loading

Answer (score 71, accepted):

restarting `ng serve` worked for me

Comment: I keep coming back to this answer. I've shouted "I forgot this _again_?!" at least 5 times in past few months.

Comment: I cannot find that command in **node_modules/.bin** directory.

Comment: @zennin, if you're referring to `ng serve`, it's entered in terminal. Also, it's specific to angular cli. If you aren't using angular cli then you won't be able to run `ng serve`. More [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli).

Comment: @user3414799 I got this error while compiling with `--aot` can you please help me?

Comment: I swear, I even remember restarting it - but this was it ‍♂️

Comment: angular also following ms windows style. restart and 98% problems get solved automatically. btw, `ng serve` helped me too..

Answer (score 42):

For newer Angular versions (10+?) lazy loading is done using the following syntax:

```
{ path: "foos", loadChildren: () => import ("./foos/foo.module").then(m => m.FooModule) },
```

---

I met a similar issue when working with Angular 4.4.5 and webpack and managed to fix it without using strings, but module type reference (much easier to write and less error prone):

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: () => TestModule }
];
```

I could not find the minimum version for Angular (loader) the supports this syntax.

---

A way that might work with AOT is to replace lambda syntax with a regular one:

```
export function getTestModule() { return TestModule; }

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: getTestModule }
];
```

---

Also check [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10673#issuecomment-391850980) (thanks to `rey_coder`).

Comment: I would prefere this solution but i does not work for me. `ERROR in Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Reference to a local (non-exported) symbol 'appRoutes'. Consider exporting the symbol (position 8:7 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol AppRoutingModule`

Comment: @Pascal - how is your module exported? I simply export it without `default`: `export class TestModule { }`

Comment: @Alexei How to use it, import TestModule in app.routes and then use it like ``loadChildren: () => TestModule`` ? I'm doing similarly with my app but getting above mentioned error ERROR in Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. and if I do it with string I get ``cannot-find-module``

Comment: @Sam - unfortunately, you are right. I had to use `loadChildren` with the path.

Comment: Thank you so much! this helped tremendously! You helped us out of a literal misery!

Comment: This worked for me... angular cli version 6.0.8. I got to follow the issue [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10673#issuecomment-391850980) on github

Comment: DANGER!!!! THIS DOES NOT FIX YOUR PROBLEM!! THIS BREAKS LAZY LOADING!! Since your  loadChildren reference is a function, is it bundled WITH your main app chunk using this method. DO NOT DO THIS if you want to lazy load your module!!

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me. thanks.

Answer (score 34):

I have faced this same issue. I solved it by doing following 2 things:

In root module's route configuration, use `loadChildren` with a relative path to the lazy loaded angular module. The string is delimited with a # where the right side of split is the lazy loaded module's class name.

I have added ./ as prefix to the `loadChildren` string.

```
{ path:'user', loadChildren:'./app/user/user.module#UserModule'}
```

I am using webpack 2 and it needs a loader for Angular 2 that enables string-based module loading with the Angular Router. Add this to the project

```
yarn add angular-router-loader -D
```

then add the `angular-router-loader` to typescript loaders

```
loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.ts$/,
    loaders: [
    'awesome-typescript-loader',
    'angular-router-loader'
    ]
  }
]
```

and its working for me.

Comment: I had to omit the `app` part also: `{ path:'user', loadChildren:'./user/user.module#UserModule'}`

Comment: @Jasnan where to add this `loaders`, I don't know which file it is

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya `loaders` are in `webpack.config.js` file. But if you're using `angular-cli` you won't have this file unless you will use `ng eject`, but it's not recommended in projects build with `angular-cli`

Answer (score 19):

For people who are using a **recent Angular version** (v9 in my case), you can setup your route with the following syntax declaration:

```
import { TestModule } from './modules/test.module';
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'blogs', loadChildren: () => import('./modules/test.module').then(m => m.TestModule) },
];

// NgModule
// declarations
// imports
// providers
// bootstrap

export class AppModule { }
```

Another way (without making the import at the top):

```
    const appRoutes: Routes = [
      { path: 'blogs', loadChildren: () => import('./modules/test.module').then(m => m.TestModule) },
    ];
```

Comment: the first way, is it really needed? seems to me that TestMudule is never used... the import that's working is the one in () => import

Comment: This of all the answers have solved my problem, not the ng serve restart nor the relative paths. Upvoting so this would come top as accepted answer.

Comment: In Angular 9 this solved my problem! I used the second version without the import at the top. Thanks so much for sharing!

Answer (score 12):

Finally I found out that I need to import lazy loaded module in routing config this way:

```
const routes: Routes = [
   { path: '', loadChildren: 'app/test.module' }
];
```

without any `/` or `./`in front of module path.

Comment: Actually both are valid, you also need to keep the path like that + restart ng serve

Comment: This answer worked for me. But not the restart ng-serve answer.

Comment: I found the exact opposite to be true, ./ worked for me not app

Comment: Removing `./` and adding `app/` worked for me on an Angular CLI project.

Answer (score 4):

In Angular 9 I did this and it worked for me:
`loadChildren: () => import('./items/items.module').then(m => m.ItemsModule)`

You can have a look on [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules)

Answer (score 3):

I change this

```
{
            path: 'test',
            loadChildren: 'app/tests/test.module#TestModule'

}
```

for this

```
   {
        path: 'test', loadChildren: () => new Promise(resolve => {
            (require as any).ensure([], require => {
                resolve(require('app/tests/test.module').TestModule);
            })
        })
    },
```

And solved my problem.

Comment: thanks!  this was the only thing that worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

> It was worked for me by using.
>
> `../app/`
>
> I solved this issue by using the suggestion popup in VS code. You can
>   also follow that. No need to go anywhere. (I Think, the path may vary in
>   every project.)

Answer (score 2):

I've been troubleshooting this for a a couple of hours on a project I've just taken over from. None of the above solutions were working, but then I realised that all the lazy-loaded modules had the .ts extension.

If anyone else is having issues, check if you need to change `loadChildren: 'app/example.module.ts'` to `loadChildren: 'app/example.module'`.

Answer (score 1):

In a use-case scenario to segregate a distinct feature (e.g. test.module.ts) from its root application (i.e. app.module.ts) through a lazily-loaded module, we could create the test module and it's components in a sub-folder (e.g. src/app/test/). The test-routing.module could be configured this way:

```
//test-routing.module.ts
//routes to test.component.ts as an example

import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { TestComponent } from './test.component';

const feature_test_routes: Routes = [

    { 
        path: '',
        component: TestComponent
    }

];

export const TestRoutingModule = RouterModule.forChild(feature_test_routes);
```

The "parent" module (app-routing.module.ts), would have a route that looks like this:

```
//app-routing.module.ts
//routes to http://localhost:4200/test

import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
const root_routes: Routes = [

    { 
        path: '',
        component: AppComponent, 
        children: [
            {
                path: 'test',
                loadChildren: './test/test.module#TestModule'
            }
        ]
    }

];

export const AppRoutingModule = RouterModule.forChild(root_routes);
```

This allows the root application and entry component, imperatively loaded, to subsequently lazy-load features from test.module.ts as a child when needed.

Answer (score 1):

make sure to include
 import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
in the module to load lazely

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I just restarted the server and it worked. :)

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my own issue. Don't put the `.ts` in the path name. Rather than using `'path/to/my/module.ts#MyModuleClass'`, use `'path/to/my/module#MyModuleClass'`

Answer (score 1):

In my case the path shared the same route as one I declared elsewhere, assuming they would be relative paths. e.g like below in the

**Not Working**

Admin Module

```
    {
    path: 'organisation',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
      loadChildren: './organisation/organisation.module#AdminOrganisationModule',
    },
```

User Module

```
    {
    path: 'organisation',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
      loadChildren: './organisation/organisation.module#UserOrganisationModule',
    },
```

individually, when only one was declared, these were working fine, but not together as it complained about the ./organisation/organisation.module path , I changed both to the pattern below and it was ok.

**Working**

Admin Module

```
    {
    path: 'organisation',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
      loadChildren: '../admin/organisation/organisation.module#AdminOrganisationModule',
    },
```

User Module

```
        {
    path: 'organisation',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
      loadChildren: '../user/organisation/organisation.module#UserOrganisationModule',
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
export default class TestModule { }
```

to

```
export class TestModule { }
```

That should fix your problems

Answer (score 0):

in my project i resolved the issue by changing the relative path to start from `src`

so instead of

`loadChildren: () => import('./user/user.module') .then(m => m.UserModule)`

I changed to:

`loadChildren: () => import('./src/app/user/user.module') .then(m => m.UserModule)`

Folder structure was:
[image]