# Cannot find module error in angular routing

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-routing, angular-router

My Angular project folder structure is

```
+-- app.module.ts
+-- app-routing.ts
+-- app.component.ts
+-- product/
|   +-- product.module.ts
|   +-- product-routing.ts
|   +-- product-detail/
|   |   +--product-detail.component.ts
|   |   +--product-detail.component.html
```

In my app-routing.ts

```
{path:'products',loadChildren:'app/product/product.module#ProductModule'}
```

In my product-routing.ts

```
{ path: 'detail', component: ProductDetailComponent }
```

When I load the url - page/product/detail , I get the following error

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module "app/product/product.module".
>   Error: Cannot find module "app/product/product.module".

**Steps tried**
tried changing 'app/product/product.module#ProductModule' to
'./product/product.module#ProductModule'. not solved.

Where I have went wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: restart  ng serve

Comment: 'product' or 'products'? Subfolder includes 's' at the end and all configs/routings as well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 lazy loading module error 'cannot find module'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39932969/angular2-lazy-loading-module-error-cannot-find-module)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `loadChildren` for lazy module loading

I have create a demo on **[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-to-hide-navigation-side-bar-in-login-page-in-angular-4-proj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)**

```
{path:'products',loadChildren: './product/product.module#ProductsModule''}
```

Comment: Excellent solution :)

Comment: Yes it worked, it would be great if you explain why loadChildren: () =>ProductsModule works but not loadChildren:'app/products/products.module#ProductModule'

Comment: It is working because it is not lazy loaded anymore!

Comment: you can do something like this as well : 
loadChildren:'./java/java.module#JavaModule'

Answer (score 1):

That can be solved by removing your typo mistake. You declared Product Module & in routing you are calling Products Module (which is not). Change to:

```
{path: 'products', loadChildren: './product/product.module#ProductModule'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [this approach](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules), I used it for **Angular 9**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'customers',
    loadChildren: () => import('./customers/customers.module').then(m => m.CustomersModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'orders',
    loadChildren: () => import('./orders/orders.module').then(m => m.OrdersModule)
  }
];
```